# SQL tables design issue(Django)

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I need to build a system which contains 6 tables,the problem is like this:
I have a Days table which every column is a date(for example 20/11/13).
Each row in Days table need to point to a Hours Table ,and each column in Hours Table is a hour (11 am or 11 pm and so on..).
Each row in Hours table need to point to a Minutes Table and this is the final table.
So we have here a 3 layers table

Days Table(each Row point to individual Hours Table)

Hours Table(each Row point to individual Minutes Table)

Minutes Table contain some data about each minute.

How Do I design such structure in Django? can I do it with models?

I have try to design it in Django like this,but I feel that ,it is the wrong way of design.

```
class DaysTable(models.Model):
    day_val= models.DataField()
    hour_key=models.ForeignKey(HoursTable)

class HoursTable(models.Model):
    hour_val= models.DataField()
    minute_key=models.ForeignKey(MinutesTable)

class MinutesTable(models.Model):
    minute_val= models.DataField()
    data_key=models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider replacing those 3 tables with a simple [django datefield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield), this way you'll ensure dates validity etc.

if you need those fields separated in the UI, take the relevant part in the view.

Comment: Excellent answer clean and simple